# Exception when passing instances between AppDomains with ApplicationBase

Tags: .net, remoting, appdomain

I'm creating an `AppDomain` with a different `ApplicationBase`, and then loading an assembly from outside of this `ApplicationBase` into the domain.

Instantiating a MarshalByRef type from it with `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` works just fine, and I can even use that type—until I try to pass an instance of a custom type as an argument to it. Even if `this` and the argument are from the exact same assembly, I get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Object type cannot be converted to target type.
```

When I don't set `ApplicationBase` the problem goes away. But I need to set this. Why is this happening? How can I get around this issue? Here is a full test case:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace adtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationBase = "C:\\", // just to have it be different.
                ApplicationName = "test server"
            };

            AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
                ads.ApplicationName, null, ads);

            ReverseFactory rf = (ReverseFactory)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
                typeof(ReverseFactory).Assembly.Location,
                typeof(ReverseFactory).FullName);

            string res = rf.Reverse(
                new StringHolder("Hello from Bizarro Domain"));

            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }

    public class ReverseFactory : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string Reverse(StringHolder s)
        {
            return new string(s.Value.Reverse().ToArray());
        }
    }

    public class StringHolder : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public StringHolder(string s) { Value = s; }
    }
}
```

When I make `StringHolder` serializable instead of MarshalByRef it works. However, my actual much larger code that this test represents can not use a serializable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample code I understand that you want to pass a proxy object from your main AppDomain (`StringHolder`), to the proxy object in the child AppDomain (`ReverseFactory`). At the same time you want the two AppDomains to have different base dirs.

One way to achieve this is by installing the assembly to the `GAC`. There probably is another way to handle this but, at the moment, it escapes me.

Comment: Thanks, putting things into the GAC is how I resolved the issue.